# Pagination count issue in custom varient collection

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have created a custom collection using `Varien_Data_Collection`. I am using this collection in a `Grid`. Everything works fine if I load the page without any filter but when tried to filter a column then pagination count was not showing fine. it's showing only 1 instead of 3 pages **but there are 68 items in the collection and the count was also wrong**.

When i tried to change the limit, then the values are displaying in the same page.

```
    protected function initColumns()
    {
      parent::initColumns();
      $columns['email_attribute']=  array(
            'header' => 'Email Filter',
            'index' => 'email_attribute',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterSponsortEmail'),
      );


    } 
    protected function _filterSponsortEmail($collection, $column)
    {
        $tmp = new Varien_Data_Collection();
        $this->getCollection()->setPageSize(5);
        foreach ($this->getCollection()->getItems() as $item) {
            if($item['email_attribute'] =="2") {
                $tmp->addItem($item);
            }
        }

        $this->setCollection($tmp);        
        return $this;
    }
```